# I want a calendar show up when i click on a input text field.Do i need to change anything in the following code?

Tags: visualforce

/* How to show a calendar to this input field? It is bit high priority*/

```
                 </apex:outputtext>
                 </apex:outputPanel>

                 <apex:inputtext id="inlineDatid" value="{!a.newDateVal}"  rendered="{!IF(a.forShowDate == 'trueval',true,false)}" />

                 </apex:column>
```

Answer (score 4):

Unless you want to reverse-engineer the platform's underlying JavaScript (or use a third party date picker), the only way is to use an `apex:inputField` where its value is an SObject date field. This is fine if you want the date to be set there, but not so fine if you just want to have a date property on a class which looks like your case. The work-around there is to re-use an existing SObject date field or create a custom SObject with a date field just for this purpose and transfer the date to/from this field.

If this seems crazy to you, vote here [Create date fields in visualforce without salesforce object](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrpmAAC).

Answer (score 1):

If you can use HTML 5 you can use the new [`<apex:input>` component](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_input.htm). Any browser or device should render their own input specific element based on the type parameter.

**update:**
Do know that at this time (2014) broswer support for this HTML5 element is still low!: [caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime).

Controller:

```
Public String MyDate{get;set;}
```

Visualforce:

```
<apex:page controller="lookupRerenderController" docType="html-5.0">
    <apex:form >
         <apex:input value="{!myDate}" id="theTextInput" type="date"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Browser support for this approach is limited at the moment - see http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!!! But I don't want to modify above my code functionality ,Just i need calendar in that input.Is there any modifications possible?

Comment: Yes @KeithC, I upvoted your answer but still think this component should be mentioned. In time support should grow.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke Fair enough. Just important that people understand that the support is surprisingly poor at the moment for such a useful feature.